# VBA #1004 using Range(Cells(,),Cells(,))

Tags: vba, copy, range

I get an Error #1004 when running the following code:

```
Sub Test()
      Worksheets("Snapshot").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10, 2)).Copy _
      Destination:=Worksheets("Snapshot2").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10, 2))
End Sub
```

But when I change to this

```
Sub Test()
      Worksheets("Snapshot").Range("A1:B10").Copy _
      Destination:=Worksheets("Snapshot2").Range("A1:B10")
End Sub
```

it works fine.

Is there a solution to run this code using Cells`( , )`? Or do I have to build a String that shows the `(" : ")` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When unqualified, `Cells` refers by default to the cells of the currently active sheet. You're getting that error because you're looking in sheet "Snapshot" (or "Snapshot2") for cells that are in a different sheet (the currently active one).

You can either fully qualify `Cells`, preferably using variables:

```
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Set sht1 = Worksheets("Snapshot")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("Snapshot2")
sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(1, 1), sht1.Cells(10, 2)).Copy _
    Destination:=sht2.Range(sht2.Cells(1, 1), sht2.Cells(10, 2))
```

Or, and I prefer this, use `Resize`:

```
Dim rangeHeight As Long
Dim rangeWidth As Long
rangeHeight = 10
rangeWidth = 2
Worksheets("Snapshot").Cells(1, 1).Resize(rangeHeight, rangeWidth).Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Snapshot2").Cells(1, 1).Resize(rangeHeight, rangeWidth)
```

Answer (score 0):

First one works fine for me, perhaps try this -

```
Sub Test()
      Worksheets("Snapshot").Range(Worksheets("Snapshot").Cells(1, 1), _
            Worksheets("Snapshot").Cells(10, 2)).Copy _
      Destination:=Worksheets("Snapshot2").Range(Worksheets("Snapshot2").Cells(1, 1), _
            Worksheets("Snapshot2").Cells(10, 2))
End Sub
```