# Seeing Error 104 when attempting copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble copying and pasting content from Shout workbook to MontlyRepTool workbook - seeing runtime 1004 error with the last part highlighted. I've tried every copy and paste method but continuously seeing the same error appear. See code beneath:

```
Sub CopyDailyShout2M()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim DailyShout As String
Dim MonthRep As String
Dim Dataset As Workbook
Dim MonthlyRepTool As Workbook
Dim shout As Workbook

    myFile = "Dataset"
    otherFile = "Monthly Reporting Tool"
    shoutFile = "Copy of Daily Shout"

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like myFile & "*" Then
           Set Dataset = Workbooks(wb.Name)
        End If
    Next wb
    
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like otherFile & "*" Then
           Set MonthlyRepTool = Workbooks(wb.Name)
        End If
    Next wb
    
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like shoutFile & "*" Then
           Set shout = Workbooks(wb.Name)
        End If
    Next wb
    
    'Counting last row and last column of the Daily Shout File (for copy and paste purposes)
    LastRow = shout.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = shout.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
shout.Worksheets(1).Range(shout.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1), shout.Worksheets(1).Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Copy _
MonthlyRepTool.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(MonthlyRepTool.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 1))

        
        
End Sub
```

Comment: In the statement `shout.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))`, you are not qualifying `Cells`. In that case VBA assumes `Cells` to be in the Activesheet, and that will fail as those cells are not part of the `shout.Worksheets(1)`-sheet. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/36494786/7599798

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the code to incorporate this but still seeing the same error. Edits made above.

Comment: Does the `MonthlyRepTool` actually hold a workbook (`? MonthlyRepTool is not nothing` in the immediate window) by the time you get to the copy operation and does it contain `"Sheet3"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error (now corrected) was a problem when specifying the source-range. Your new problem is with your destination range: `MonthlyRepTool.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(MonthlyRepTool.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 1))` will not work. The `Range`-method can be called with one or two parameters. If called with one parameter, this must be a string specifying the range, eg "A1". Only when called with two parameters, you specify two cells that define start and end cell (see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.range).
As Cells are also ranges, you can simply write `MonthlyRepTool.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 1)` as destination (or use `MonthlyRepTool.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")`, whatever fits best.)

When you have statements like that, it is really hard to see an error. It's always a good idea to break such statements into smaller pieces.

Define source and destination range as variables

```
Dim sourceRange as Range, destRange as Range
With shout.Worksheets(1)
     Set sourceRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
End With
Set destRange = MonthlyRepTool.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 1)
sourceRange.Copy destRange
```

Your first code (before the edit) would have been

```
Set sourceRange = shout.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
```

and throw a runtime error already at this stage - showing you that you have an issue with the source range definition (not with the dest range, not with the `Copy`-method).
Similarly,

```
Set destRange = MonthlyRepTool.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(MonthlyRepTool.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 1))
```

would have given you a runtime error telling that you have an issue with defining the destination range.

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm now seeing Run-time error 450 - wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment & can't figure out why. Any ideas here?

Comment: Sorry, Cut&Paste error from my testcode - the `With`-statement had an extra `Range`. Corrected.